# How to reference an image within HTML tag in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I understand that rails assets eg. an image in assets/images/ get a cache helper number appended to them ie. `background.jpg` may become `background77bfb376c1e.jpg` and therefore, a helper must be used to reference them e.g.

```
asset-url("background.png", image)
```

However.. How could I reference background.jpg in a HTML tag such as this:

```
<header class="pt100 pb100 parallax-window-2" data-image-src="background.jpg">
```

? Apologies in advance if the solutions is obvious ...

Comment: Have you tried `data-image-src="/assets/images/background.jpg"`?

Comment: If you want to use helpers, then you can use `image_tag` like so `<header class="pt100 pb100 parallax-window-2" data-image-src="<%= image_tag(background) %>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<header class="pt100 pb100 parallax-window-2" data-image-src=<%= image_path('background.jpg') %>>
```

Hope that helps!